# Rails 3: Using a submit button to update a model attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, button, radio-button

I have a user model which contains an "email switch" column with a boolean value. I'd like to create a button in my view which allows the user to turn "on" and "off" their emails. I can't get the submit button to update the value in the User model.

```
   <%= form_for :user do |f| %>
        <label>On</label>
        <%= f.radio_button :email_switch, true %>
        <label>Off</label>
        <%= f.radio_button :email_switch, false %>
        <%= f.submit "Save", :controller => "dashboard_emails", :action => "update", :method => "put" %>
    <% end %>


class DashboardEmailsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :require_user

  def index
  end

  def update

  end

  private

  def require_user
    @user = @logged_in_user
  end


class User
  field :email_switch, type: Boolean, default: false
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the arguments to `form_for` not to the `f.submit` call. If you have a persisted user assigned to `@user` you should be able to do:

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
    <label>On</label>
    <%= f.radio_button :email_switch, true %>
    <label>Off</label>
    <%= f.radio_button :email_switch, false %>
    <%= f.submit "Save" %>
<% end %>
```

Of course you need `resources :users` in your `config/routes.rb` to get this working. This should then send a PUT request to `/users/47`, which in turn fires the `#update` action of your `UsersController`

Comment: This form is being placed inside the User's dashboard which means it should update to http://localhost:3000/dashboard/emails and not the user's ID. I'm confused as to how I can go about making sure that the form posts to the correct location and not to http://localhost:3000/users/#{user.id}